# Compute the integral $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+1} e^{-t^2} \, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, gaussian-integral

I am asking myself if there is any way of computing Gaussian integrals of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+1} e^{-t^2} \, dt,$$
i.e. integrating over all of $\mathbb R^+$ but leaving out "half" the intervals. Maybe there is no precise value but a way of expressing it in terms of other functions?

I previously asked a question which was stated not in the way I actually intended it to be and thus led to a more trivial answer, see [Gaussian integral over a union of intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492856/gaussian-integral-over-a-union-of-intervals)

Comment: Have you tried any tricks of a similar flavour just to see what happens? e.g. first thing I would do is substitute $t \mapsto t\pm1$ and just stare it at again. (I don't have a solution that I'm hinting at I'm just throwing things out there). I suppose the things I'm getting at are well known techniques like "Do a substitution/parts and then relate it back to the original integral or relate it to a standard integral"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can obtain a closed form for that sum. But you can get an expression in terms of the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function#Definition).

Let
$$f(x)=\int_{|x|}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$
We can rewrite the sum in question as
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+1} e^{-t^2} \, dt &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[ f(2n)-f(2n+1)\right] \\
&=\frac 1 2\left(f(0)+\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} f(2n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} f(2n+1)\right)
\end{split}$$
By the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Forms_of_the_equation),
$$\left\{
\begin{split}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} f(2n)&=\frac 1 2 \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat f\left(\frac n 2\right)\\
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} f(2n+1)&=\frac 1 2 \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}e^{i\pi n}\hat f\left(\frac n 2\right)
\end{split}
\right.$$
We obtain

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+1} e^{-t^2} \, dt=\frac 1 4\left(2f(0)+\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat f\left(\frac n 2\right) -\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^n\hat f\left(\frac n 2\right)   \right)=\frac 1 2\left(f(0)+\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat f\left(\frac {2n+1} 2\right)  \right)$$

Now, for the Fourier transform of $f$,
$$\begin{split}
\hat f(\xi) &= \int_{\mathbb R}e^{-2i\pi\xi x}f(x)dx\\
&=2\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(2\pi \xi x)f(x)dx\\
&=2\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(2\pi \xi x)\int_x^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dtdx\\
&=2\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\int_0^{x}\cos(2\pi \xi x)dx dt\\
&= 2\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\frac{\sin(2\pi\xi t)}{2\pi \xi}dt\\
&=\frac{D(\pi \xi)}{\pi \xi}
\end{split}$$
where $D$ is the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function#Definition). To recap,
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+1} e^{-t^2} \, dt =\frac 1 2\left(\frac  {\sqrt{\pi}}2 +\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{D\left(\frac {2n+1}2 \pi\right)}{\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi}\right)}$$

Comment: Very neat, thank you! I will see if anyone else has an idea and accept your answer in a few days :)